# Is the caller of a Windows program responsible for adding \\?\ to long file name arguments

Tags: windows, winapi, cmd, executable, command-line-arguments

In my Java program, I am using a command line library to fork a Java process. This fails (depending on how the program is used) when the file path of the JAR file that I pass in the `java.exe -jar` call exceeds the 260 character path length limit of Windows. (The error message is `Error: Unable to access jarfile` followed by the path name.) I can make the Java call work by (manually) adding a `\\?\` prefix to the JAR file name. This solves the one particular problem instance, but is this generally the right approach?

Should I expect Windows programs to correctly handle long paths passed as command line arguments, - or - is it the caller's responsibility to detect long paths and to add the `\\?\` prefix?

Or less general: Is there a bug in the `java.exe` or in the command line library?

Answer (score 0):

Most programs will simply take the filename and pass it as-is to an API function, like `CreateFile()`.  So in that case, it would indeed be the caller's responsibility to detect a long filename and prefix it accordingly before passing it around.